# Does math scare users?

Tags: user-behavior, user-expectation

On most food containers, they say:

> Sugars less than 1g.

Why don't they just say:

> < 1g

**Do users not like math in any context? Even if the math helps summarize and shorten content?**

Comment: not sure user is the best way to describe someone reading a food container.

Comment: The question title and content do not match up. Food labelling is something that is generally highly regulated by governments, and there are restrictions on what can/can't be printed on the label. Extrapolating 'users don't like maths [symbols]' from that is a massive leap.

Comment: Not sure why this is getting down voted. Does the idea of users being scared of math scare people?

Answer (score 10):

**It is used**

According to the FDA's guidelines it is perfectly acceptable to shorten "less than" to the symbol "<".

> (i) The name of each nutrient, as specified in paragraph (c) of this section, shall be given in a column and followed immediately by the quantitative amount by weight for that nutrient appended with a “g” for grams or a “mg” for milligrams as shown in paragraph (d)(12) of this section. **The symbol “<” may be used in place of “less than.”**
>
> [§101.9   Nutrition labeling of food.](http://www.ecfr.gov/cgi-bin/retrieveECFR?gp=1&SID=4bf49f997b04dcacdfbd637db9aa5839&ty=HTML&h=L&mc=true&n=pt21.2.101&r=PART#se21.2.101_19)

[image]

I am not sure if it is truly more or less used than the words "less than", but if it is less than I would assume it is simply to be more verbose and ensure the reader understands.

**EDIT:** 
As Midas pointed out in the comments UK regulations show similar guidelines:

> These guidelines cover the amounts of nutrients that can be regarded as
>   negligible and can therefore be declared as **“0g” or as "< X g"**
>
> [TECHNICAL GUIDANCE ON NUTRITION
>   LABELLING](https://www.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/207842/2013-06-19_Nutrition_Technical_Guidance.pdf)

Seemingly not even giving the "less than" option.

Comment: Likewise in the UK based on EU guidelines, see page 24: https://www.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/207842/2013-06-19_Nutrition_Technical_Guidance.pdf

Comment: @Midas good find, that page doesn't even seem to have a textual "less than" labeling option only the symbol.

Comment: +1 for visual proof, makes it a lot easy when user scans.

Answer (score 0):

> Why don't they just say Sugars < 1g ?

**Because not all intended users/readers are fluent enough in math shorthand**

Plus and minus symbols? Sure. Greater and less than symbols... not so much. Of course, *lots* of people understand these easily, but it's a massive assumption to think that 'everyone' gets them.

I was once taking part in a card game before which two other (PhD-level) participants suggested that the most efficient way to describe the way the cards should be dealt is "Deal *n*-1 cards".

The counter argument is: that's only efficient if all users are equally knowledgeable about the algebraic concept of *n*. If my middle-aged small-town home-maker Mom was in the group, she would have have no idea what *n*-1 means and the efficiency of the instruction would be lost.

In that case, and in this one, **the most efficient and effective method is the one that's most understandable to most people.**